# Meteor.js Routing with an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections, meteor, iron-router

I have a collection of questions, each question with an id:

```
[
  {
    id: 0,
    question: "What's up?"
},
```

.....

I also have a collection of question lists/arrays. Each item in the list/array is a questions id.

I have a template to link to the questions in the list:

```
<template name="questionListIDContent">
    {{#each question}}
        <a href="{{pathFor 'myQuestion'}}" class="discuss btn btn-default btn-sm">Answer</a>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

The route is:

```
    Router.route('/myquestion/:_id', {
  name: 'myQuestion',
  data: function() {
    return Questions.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
});
```

The helper is:

```
 Template.questionListIDContent.helpers({
  question: function() {
    var temp = QuestionsList.findOne({id: this.lessonID});
    var temp2 = temp.questionID // Array of question IDs
    return Questions.findOne({id: { $in: temp2 }});
  }
});
```

I am trying to use findOne with an array containing the list of questions to get required questions to use in the template. Anyone see what I am doing wrong here? Is there a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use findOne, use find. FindOne returns one item, so you can run over them in an each block. Find returns a cursor which you can run through with each.